# How to create a model not linked to a plugin in OctoberCMS?

Tags: model, octobercms

I'm trying OctoberCMS and I pretty much like it. Yesterday I installed the *JWT plugin* and managed to login on my website from an android app I created purposely.

Now I'd like to create some new models and expose such data to the same app, once I've logged in. In order to do so I installed the *API generator* plugin but it needs a model in order to generate the API.

I tried then to create a new model, following [the guide](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model). I created the table in the DB, the model php file but apparently that's not enough to make the model pop up in the list inside the *API generator* wizard. Also I'm stuck because of two main issues:
1- I don't know how to create a plugin-unrelated model. I'd like my model to be available to all the users of the website and free from plugin dependencies. How to do so?
2- What's needed in order to create a model? The guide tells about creating the model file but apparently it's not enough to make it availale. Do I need to launch some artisan command?

Thank you for anybody who will provide any hint on this

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you are not able to generate standalone model, as October is `CMS` and it depends on plugins.

so to avoid thisissues

you can create `dedicated plugins` for only `models` you just need to add `models` there nothing else.

these models are available `system wide` no need to worry about it.

and yes `API generator plugin` will only list `models` which are created by the `rainlab Builder` as all model list is coming from the cache. if cache is not there then only `plugin manger` will return list which will be all available models(of plugins)

infect this is great approach that you have `api generator plugin` and `your dedicated models plugin` if you need to reuse them you just need these 2 things to `next project` and modify things , you are all done.

> if model cache is not build then only new model's will be fetched through plugin manager (its applicable when you are transferring your `plugin` to other project)
>
> so to force october cms rebuild that list you can either clear cache manually

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

or you can use this plugin and use its widget.

```
https://github.com/Flynsarmy/oc-dashboardcachewidget-plugin
```

it has `readme` how to install it.